# CLion отображение символов

Tags: c++, clion

[image: Вид терминала]
Неправильно отображаются символы в сообщениях об ошибках в терминале CLion. Среди руководств в инете полезной информации не нашел, поэтому надеюсь что кто-нибудь знает как пофиксить эту проблему

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Comment: Я так думаю что там должно быть написано, `пропуск инициализации переменной из-за блока goto`. Или ТС поставил точку с запятой после `goto`

Comment: Ну то, что там должно быть написано, я знаю. Меня именно интересует, как решить проблему с отображением этих сообщений.

Comment: самый надеждный способ - это запустить инсталлятор и удалить руссификацию студии. Она только мешает. Или выбросить clion.